# Encoding a message using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i am new to python programing, and was wondering if anyone could help me with encoding a message. for example if my dictionary is {'x': 'e', 'e': 'x'} and i would like to encode 'hello world' so that is prints 'hxllo world'

```
In [  ]: encode(code, "Hello World")
Out[  ]: 'Hxllo World'
```

Comment: Unless this is homework which stipulates the use of a dictionary, it is more elegant to use the string method `translate`. See this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm

Comment: yes i came across it on an exercise file which asks to  use a dictionary to complete the task

Comment: What is `code` in `encode`, is that just the dictionary?

Comment: Using a dictionary, there is a 1-line answer of the from `return ''.join(...)` where `...` is replaced by an appropriate comprehension.

Comment: @RoadRunner yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `translate` like so:

1. define your dictionary
2. use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to create translation table `transtable`
3. finally do [`"mystring".translate(transtable)`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)
4. 'hxllo world', which is the required output

this makes use of the dictionary you are required to use. Just pass that dictionary as your `code` to your function `encode`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def encode(code, string):
    result = ""
    for char in string:
        if char in code:
            result += code[char]
        else:
            result += char
    return result
```

Output:

```
>>> print(encode(d, "Hello World"))
Hxllo World
```